# memory leak when loading and unloading textures

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know why there is a memory leak when loading and unloading textures to memory? Memory leak asserts under specific conditions

I have a texture class. The code is below:
**Texture.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "../../vendor/headers/stb_image.h"

class Texture {
    friend class BatchRenderer;
    // Object
    private:
        unsigned int textureID, textureSlot;
        unsigned char* image;
        int width, height, bpp;
    public:
        Texture(const std::string& path); // To-Do: Replace "const std::string& path" with a char array. "const std::string& path" is alive for the lifetime of the program.
        Texture(const char* path);

        unsigned int getTextureID() const;
        int getTextureSlot() const;
        unsigned int getWidth() const;
        unsigned int getHeight() const;
        unsigned int getBPP() const;

        ~Texture();
};
```

**Texture.cpp**

```
#include "Texture.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// To-Do: Replace "const std::string& path" with a char array. "const std::string& path" is alive for the lifetime of the program.
Texture::Texture(const std::string& path) : textureID(0), image(nullptr), width(0), height(0), bpp(0) {
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    image = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, 4);

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    textureSlot = 0;
}

Texture::Texture(const char* path) {
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    image = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &bpp, 4);

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    textureSlot = 0;
}

unsigned int Texture::getTextureID() const {
    return textureID;
}

int Texture::getTextureSlot() const {
    return textureSlot;
}

unsigned int Texture::getWidth() const {
    return width;
}

unsigned int Texture::getHeight() const {
    return height;
}

unsigned int Texture::getBPP() const {
    return bpp;
}

Texture::~Texture() {
    if (image)
        stbi_image_free(image);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textureID);
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "batchrenderer/classes/Texture.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Program operating..." << endl;

    string pause;
    
    cout << "Enter anything to continue: ";
    cin >> pause;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Texture* texture = new Texture("C:\\Users\\chris\\source\\repos\\BatchRenderer\\BatchRenderer\\resources\\coloredsquares\\black.png");
        delete(texture);
    }
    cout << "Enter anything to continue: ";
    cin >> pause;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Texture* texture = new Texture("C:\\Users\\chris\\source\\repos\\BatchRenderer\\BatchRenderer\\resources\\coloredsquares\\black.png");
        delete(texture);
    }
    cout << "Enter anything to continue: ";
    cin >> pause;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Texture* texture = new Texture("C:\\Users\\chris\\source\\repos\\BatchRenderer\\BatchRenderer\\resources\\coloredsquares\\black.png");
        delete(texture);
    }

    cout << "Enter anything to continue: ";
    cin >> pause;

    cout << "Program terminated..." << endl;
}
```

Here is what my diagnostics tool looks like. I am not sure if there is a small bug in the VS code and there is actually no memory leak or if there is a memory leak and it is something SO small that I cannot pin point it. When the code is profiled with a loop of 100 times, there is no leak. The memory leak only asserts when the loop exceeds 1000 loops. Does anyone know anything about why this is happening. Note: there appear to be no memory leak when only 1 texture is load. Or maybe there is, but it is negligible until you have created a LOT of Texture objects.
[image]

Note: I was suspecting it was the string object but did not find anything when I profiled that specific thing. Unless I profiled it wrong.

Comment: Q: Are you using MSVS 2022 (per your tag), which has a built-in profiler?  Or using VS Code (which is the IDE you mention in your post, and which relies on plugins)?  Please clarify 1) your platform (Windows?), 2) which IDE you're using (MSVS? VSCode? Other?), 3) exactly which tool you're using to "profile".  And, if VSCode, 4) specify which C++ compiler.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 community edition and I am using its integrated compiler for visual studio. I am using its built-in diagnostics tool. My OS is Windows 11.

Comment: Also, The graph shows memory stayed allocated, but when I hover over it, it states that there is only 2MB which is what the program started with memory allocated. Weird

Comment: I don't know `GL`, just a guess: in your `Texture::~Texture()`, shouldn't you `glDeleteTextures` before `stbi_image_free`?

Comment: I made the change and the diagnostic tool shows the same behaviour.

Comment: You have *not* found a "bug in MSVS (Visual Studio).  FYI, "VS Code" is often used as an abbreviation for "Microsoft Visual Studio Code", which is very definitely a *DIFFERENT* product/different IDE than "Microsoft Visual Studio" (MSVS).  People often conflate the two.

Comment: Where is the opengl context created? OpenGL does not give you any guarantee on when memory is really freed. It might simply keep the memory allocated to reuse it in future. All the memory should be freed though when the context gets deleted.

Comment: There is no memory leak; you've just seen a small bump and decided it's a leak. It is not. It's common for your process to acquire few more pages of memory due to heap fragmentation and how heap allocators work, even if you correctly free all your allocations.